# How to set location in nginx configuration for redirected url?

Tags: zend-framework, nginx, routes, php

I use Zend Framework. And here is router initializaion:

```
protected function _initRouter()
    {
        $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
        $translatorRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                        ':lang/:controller/:action/*',
                        array(
                            'lang' => 'en',
                            'controller' => 'index',
                            'action' => 'index'
                        )
        );

        $staticRouter = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                        '/:lang/s/:name',
                        array(
                            'lang' => 'en',
                            'controller' => 'static',
                            'action' => 'index',
                            'name' => ''
                        )
        );

        $router->addRoute('translator', $translatorRoute);
        $router->addRoute('static', $staticRouter);

        return $router;
    }
```

So example.com/ will be directed to example.com/en/

Here is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    charset UTF-8;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    index index.php;
    root $root_path;
    set $root_path /var/www/example.com;
    listen 80;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;

    location /application/                { deny all; }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $root_path/index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        root $root_path;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
   }   
}
```

example.com is redirected to example.com/en/ well but example.com/en/ returns 404 error. If I add location section:

```
location /en/ {...
```

we will get recursion. How to avoid it and run /en/ page?

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use regexp for such rediretcs? Or use */en location.

Comment: seems it would be recursion because index.php redirect to /en/

Comment: Try smth like ^~ before location source - location ^~ /en/